# How to use For Loop to select one line at a time

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of items in a .txt file that I am trying to insert one at a time, run the script, then move onto the next line.

Whenever I run the script it dumps all of the information into the script at once and not one at a time. Any thoughts on how to read just one line at a time, run the script and then return to read the next line and start the process over again until the list is finished?

```
with open('SBXTest.txt') as file:
    array = file.readlines()
```

The rest of the script is acting as it should. The thing is the information in the file goes into a hyperlink, script runs, gives me back information, then I need it to run again for the next item in line.

Comment: You are probably thinking of `readline` (without the 's'). This post might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/22945372/6942527

Answer (score -1):

You can loop and do stuff in the loop for each line:

```
with open('SBXTest.txt') as file:
    array = file.readlines()
    for line in array:
        # do what you want to do with each line.
```

Thanks for @KlausD.'s opinion of a more efficient way:

```
for line in open('SBXTest.txt'):
    # do what you want to do with each line.
```

Comment: More efficient: `for line in open('SBXTest.txt'):`. BTW Python does not have arrays.

Answer (score -1):

from what I understand from the question, you want to iterate over each line of file and do some work on that

```
with open("SBXTest.txt") as file
for i, line in enumerate(file):
    DoSomeStuff(line)
```

Comment: This isn't doesn't really work, line is gonna be a tuple of the line and the line number.

Comment: Why `enumerate`?

Comment: @busybear Good question.

Comment: I did try this and it does what it is supposed to, except it adds in a space which renders the hyperlink useless so I am trying to find a way to remove that space.

Answer (score -1):

You need to loop through  **file.readline()** to get each line, like

```
for line in file.readline():
  print(line)
  # code to perform any action you'd like
```

So your code should be something like,

```
with open('SBXTest.txt') as file:
  for line in file.readline():
    # code to perform any action you'd like
```

You may use **enumerate(file)** instead of **file.readline()** if the row indices are required as it returns a dictionary of the format *[ line_num1 : line1, line_num2: line2 ..... line_numN, lineN]*.